# How to Parse the XML structure data in CPP while going and accessing each node?

Tags: c++, xml, unit-testing, xml-parsing, pugixml

I'm very new to XML parse in C++. I want to parse the XML. So, I'm using the PugiXML library. I mainly want to get the values from each of the children nodes.

Here, is the sample code till here I have written, then I don't understand what to do next.

```
void XML()
{
    //Suppose I'm getting XML data in the form of a string, and store in string variable **xmlString**

    //Using 3rd party lib Pugixml parser want to store all the **xmlString data in doc**.
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_string(xmlString.c_str());

    // I want value will store the data "Sheet1" as per the syntax. But somehow, doc store the value till here **<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?><Graphics**
    string  value = doc.child("Graphics").child("SheetInfo").attribute("SheetName").value();
}
```

Here is the sample XML data which is stored in the **xmlString**.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Graphics>
    <SheetInfo>
        <SheetName>Sheet1</SheetName>
        <Circle>
            <IGDSElement>
                <Type>89</Type>
            </IGDSElement>
            <cPt_x>0.212050</cPt_x>
            <cPt_y>0.148307</cPt_y>
            <orientation>0</orientation>
        </Circle>
    <SheetInfo>
<Graphics>
```

Please help me to parse this XML format data while going to each node.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visit each node, you can traverse it with a `for` loop:

```
    for(const auto& child : doc.child("Graphics"))
        cout << child.child_value() << endl;
```

To find specific node you can use `XPath`. [Here](http://www.gerald-fahrnholz.eu/sw/DocGenerated/HowToUse/html/group___grp_pugi_xml.html) are examples on various things commonly needed for `XML` parsing.